# Insert data in custom table during new post creation

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, database

I want to in insert data in my custom db table when creating a post.

Suppose there are three categories (php, wordpress & jquery). When i create a post in wordpress, i want to insert post id and category id in my custom database table. How can i do this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hook a function to [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) (for saves and updates) or `publish_post` for publication only. The second hook is really a variable hook of the form [`{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24new_status%7D_%7B%24post-%3Epost_type%7D) so it will be different if you aren't dealing with a `post` post type.

```
function do_on_publish_wpse_98177($id) {
  // your code; $id is the post ID
}
add_action('publish_post','do_on_publish_wpse_98177');
```

Make backups and test thoroughly on a development server. It is easy to break things with these hooks.

You can use `$id` to pull information from the database including category information. You can also access the `global` `$_POST` if you need it but these hooks run after the post save so if something has altered (another function) the data saved to the database `$_POST` might be out of sync.

See also:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions